How to flag a sequence of states in a time ordered Pyspark DataFrame
I have a DataFrame similar to:
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        [1, 100, 1],
        [1, 200, 1],
        [1, 300, 2],
        [1, 400, 2],
        [1, 500, 2],
        [1, 600, 3],
        [1, 700, 3],
        [1, 800, 4],
        [1, 900, 4],
        [1, 1000, 5],
        [1, 1100, 5],
    ],
    schema=["id","time", "value"]
)




ID
Time
Value




1
100
1


1
200
1


1
300
2


1
400
2


1
500
2


1
600
3


1
700
3


1
800
4


1
900
4


1
1000
5


1
1100
5



What I would like to create is a function that accept the column name and the sequence, and return the data frame with a 1 where the sequence is found. E.g.:
detect_sequence(df, "Value", [2, 3, 4])

And this should return



ID
Time
Value
Flag




1
100
1
0


1
200
1
0


1
300
2
1


1
400
2
1


1
500
2
1


1
600
3
1


1
700
3
1


1
800
4
1


1
900
4
1


1
1000
5
0


1
1100
5
0



Do you think this is possible without any UDF?
I tried extracting state changes and using lag functions ore multiple windowing but it's not working. Especially I cannot deal with the fact the sequence can have a flexible length, it should accept (2, 3, 4) but also (2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4) and (2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4)...
Thanks in advance

Please provide minimal reproducible code.

Does the sequence have to be in the same order as well? or it can be something like 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3 and so on...

I added the spark function to generate the example df in the question, right now this is all the working minimal reproducible code that I have. @Good_Man

No I would like to keep just the ordered sequence so [2, 3, 4,] is ok but [3, 2, 4] or [4, 3, 2] are a different sequence that should not be taken as valid @VikasSharma

I found a solution, maybe not the cleaner one but it seems to work properly:
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def detect_sequence(column, ordered_window: Window, sequence):    
    
    window_forward = ordered_window.rowsBetween(1, Window.unboundedFollowing)
    window_backward = ordered_window.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, -1)
    
    state_changes = detect_state_changes(column, ordered_window)
    
    array_col = F.when(state_changes.isNotNull(), F.array(state_changes)).otherwise(None)
    array_col_backward = F.when(state_changes.isNotNull(), F.array(state_changes)).otherwise(None)
    
    for i in range(1, len(sequence)):
        
        state_changes = F.when(array_col.isNotNull(), F.element_at(array_col, i)).otherwise(None)
        state_changes_b = F.when(array_col_backward.isNotNull(), F.element_at(array_col_backward, i)).otherwise(None)
        
        array_col = F.array_append(array_col, F.first(state_changes, True).over(window_forward))
        array_col_backward = F.array_append(array_col_backward, F.last(state_changes_b, True).over(window_backward))
    
    sequence_col = F.lit(sequence)
    reversed_sequence_col = F.lit(list(reversed(sequence)))
    
    result = F.sum(F.when(array_col == sequence_col, 1).when(array_col_backward == reversed_sequence_col, -1).otherwise(0)).over(ordered_window)
    
    # Fill last element rows
    array_col_backward_forward_fill = F.last(array_col_backward, True).over(ordered_window)
    result = F.when(array_col_backward_forward_fill == reversed_sequence_col, 1).otherwise(result)
    
    return result

And can be used like:
w = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("time")

df.withColumn("result", detect_sequence(F.col("value"), w, [2,3,4])).show()

Result:
+---+----+-----+------+
| id|time|value|result|
+---+----+-----+------+
|  1| 100|    1|     0|
|  1| 200|    1|     0|
|  1| 300|    2|     1|
|  1| 400|    2|     1|
|  1| 500|    2|     1|
|  1| 600|    3|     1|
|  1| 700|    3|     1|
|  1| 800|    4|     1|
|  1| 900|    4|     1|
|  1|1000|    5|     0|
|  1|1100|    5|     0|
+---+----+-----+------+

